# Excel pivot table - grouping data and multiple data series

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have Excel data similar to the following:

```
Category | 2008 | 2009 | 2010 |
Apples   | 100  | 150  | 200  |
Apples   | 300  | 100  | 400  |
Oranges  | 500  | 500  | 600  |
```

I'd like to group the data together.  I can write a macro to do this, but wondered if I can do this with an Excel feature such as pivot tables, before I code this.

The output would then be the following:

```
Category | 2008 | 2009 | 2010 |
Apples   | 400  | 250  | 600  |
Oranges  | 500  | 500  | 600  |
```

I realise stack overflow isn't exactly the right kind of place for this question these days, but couldn't find a more appropriate SE site to ask it in.

Comment: Yes you can do this with a Pivot Table.  Much more fun, and efficient, than coding it!  SuperUser is a good SE forum for questions about that.

Comment: Ah - hadn't thought of SU.  I was looking for an excel or office type SE, and kind of forgot about SuperUser.  The last time I asked an Excel question there only was SO! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question will probably get moved to SU, but in the meantime:

**Step 1** - Insert your pivot table using your data range:

[image: Insert Pivot]

**Step 2** - Check all the columns for inclusion. Excel will automatically detect your category labels, and the columns that you want to summarize. By default, it's done exactly what you want, but there are many configuration options to change how values are summed and displayed should you want to go to greater detail.

[image: Configure Pivot]